# javascript onclick to display time and date in a paragraph or not

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the date to appear in an empty paragraph with an ID when I click on a button. So far no luck. Don't mind if I cant get it to appear in the paragraph but just want to know how to make it appear when I click the button thanks in advance.
sorry if its a dumb one,
I have got the alert working on click but just can not seem to figure this one out
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lets Practice Some Code</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/Matteveli/Desktop/javascript practice/style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div><h1 id="topTitle"> Time and date Test</h1></div>

<div><button id="alerter">click Me to make an alert pop up.</button></div>

<p id="empty"

></p><div><button id="timeAndDate">click Me to display time and date</button></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/Matteveli/Desktop/javascript practice/javascript/funtionality.js"></script>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

```js
var alerterButton = document.getElementById("alerter");
var dateButton = document.getElementById("timeAndDate");
var emptyP = document.getElementById("empty");
var d = new Date();

// for the first click that we have working....  " THE ALERT "
//a link to function was called then the function was made
// as below 
alerterButton.onclick = myClickHandler;

function myClickHandler() {alert("the document was clicked")};

/// TIME AND DATE ???

dateButton.onclick = emptyP.innerHTML=d;

function showMeTheDate() {emptyP.innerHTML+d};
```

any help greatly appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sckjnx7t/2/

The key is engage function and event, in this case onclick, then, you could do:

```
dateButton.onclick = function(){
                                  //code here
                                 };
```

or:

```
    dateButton.onclick = showMeTheDate();
    function showMeTheDate() {
                                //code
                              };
```

Comment: nice one i used this one in the end... perfect the demo was great also thank for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`dateButton.onclick` should be a function. So, you should do

```
dateButton.onclick = () =>  { emptyP.innerHTML= d.getDate() }
```

Comment: thanks alot for the reply learned that () => is a short version of function and also worked it out from your example....this code was giving me just the day but when shortened to {emptyP.innerHTMl = d} it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Only edit your event handler function, and set pharagraph's innerHTML to d.getDate().

```
function myClickHandler() {
    alert("button was clicked!");
    emptyP.innerHTML = d.getDate();
}
```

You need to stay the function workers in same scope. Without this approach, the latest eventHandler function will be used for all time, because other (last) functions' functionality won't be.